# SQL Server query to find all current database and user names

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I need a query to find all the databases listed with their users.

Answer (score 0):

I found this query [here](https://www.pythian.com/blog/httpconsultingblogs-emc-comjamiethomsonarchive20070209sql-server-2005_3a00_-view-all-permissions-_2800_2_2900_-aspx/).

```
DECLARE @DB_USers TABLE
(DBName sysname, UserName sysname, LoginType sysname, AssociatedRole varchar(max),create_date datetime,modify_date datetime)

INSERT @DB_USers
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb

'
use [?]
SELECT ''?'' AS DB_Name,
case prin.name when ''dbo'' then prin.name + '' (''+ (select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name =''?'') + '')'' else prin.name end AS UserName,
prin.type_desc AS LoginType,
isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole ,create_date,modify_date
FROM sys.database_principals prin
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id
WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL and prin.sid NOT IN (0x00) and
prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND prin.name NOT LIKE ''##%'''

SELECT

dbname,username ,logintype ,create_date ,modify_date ,

STUFF(

(

SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),associatedrole)

FROM @DB_USers user2

WHERE

user1.DBName=user2.DBName AND user1.UserName=user2.UserName

FOR XML PATH('')

)

,1,1,'') AS Permissions_user

FROM @DB_USers user1

GROUP BY

dbname,username ,logintype ,create_date ,modify_date

ORDER BY DBName,username
```